# logger in Grails always report wrong method and line number

Tags: grails, logging

I use Grails 2.4.4 and Oracle JDK 1.7.45

The below is my logger configuration in Config.groovy:

```
log4j.main = {
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c{1}.%M(%L): %m%n')
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
    debug 'grails.app'
}
```

My controller is :

```
class HomeController {
    def index() {
        log.debug("HELLO, WORLD")
        render "HELLO, WORLD"
    }
}
```

The log result looks like below:

```
15/04/08 13:15:26.723 DEBUG HomeController.debug(128) : HELLO, WORLD
```

How do I config Config.groovy so that the log result can correctly display method and line number like below:

```
15/04/08 13:15:26.723 DEBUG HomeController.index(3) : HELLO, WORLD
```